# Trouble Connecting to SAP Through VBA in Excel Error 614

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to run a basic code I've found numerous places on here and elsewhere which should open SAP, input a command, and execute.

I've gone as far as SAP opening through VBA but I get runtime error 614 at line `Set Connection = Appl.Openconnection("1) PRD", True).Children(0)` below, in regard to setting the "session" as shown.

> Run-Time Error 614: The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SapGui As Object
Dim Connection As Object
Dim Appl As Object
Dim session As Object
Dim WshShell As Object

'Of course change for your file directory
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe", 4
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do Until WshShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon ")
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop

Set WshShell = Nothing

Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Appl = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = Appl.Openconnection("1) PRD", True).Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)


session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "cv03n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 'ENTER



'and there goes your code in SAP

End Sub
```

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Connection.Children.Count` return in the immediate window if you put it before `Set session = Connection.Children(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the name of your SAP connection. According to the example below, a corresponding command would look like this:

```
...
Set Connection = Appl.openconnection("DAL_ EHP5")
Set session = Connection.Children(0)
...
```

Furthermore, it may be possible that you first have to log into SAP.

for example:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = Mandant
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = Name
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = PW
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Regards, ScriptMan

[image: SAP Logon]

Comment: I've tried this while logged on and I get the same error, my "1) PRD" works correctly as it logs me into SAP once the VBA code is run. It just stops short of being able to execute commands within the program - as of right now password input is not required so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: See debug screen after simplifying to what you suggested:
[DEBUG 2](https://i.imgur.com/1kjqmyH.png)

Comment: Saplogon.exe is only needed if you are not yet logged into SAP. In principle, you have to distinguish between two different states: 1. You are already logged on to SAP or 2. You are not yet logged on to SAP. The fine art is to store the two states in a login script. What is your state now?

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen on accessing the `GuiConnection` object if the SAP system is configured to prevent the execution of scripts with SAP GUI Scripting.

Ask the SAP administrator to enable scripts (profile parameter `sapgui/user_scripting` to be set to `TRUE`; other possibilities are described in [SAP KBA SAP Knowledge Base Article 2296251 - How can SAP GUI Scripting be enabled?](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2296251/E)).